# How to align the choices in pickerInput to the center?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an app using RShiny.

I just found out that I can align the label (Year) of the picker input and centralize it.

However, I am not sure how I can align the choices to the center ('ALL' and the years when I select on the dropdown list.

I tried to add align = "center" into the pickerInput but I got an error.

This is how it looks like at the moment:

[image: pickerInput]

This is the code that I am using:

```
tabPanel("Price Analysis",value="Key Factors",

verticalLayout(

fluidRow(column(3 ,align = "center",

pickerInput(inputId="year_2","Year",

choices = c("All","2019", "2018","2017",'2016',"2015"),

selected = "All",

options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = F))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `options = list()` put

```
options = list(`dropdown-align-center` = TRUE)
```

That should get you what you are looking for.